# AJAX calling PHP-page, need help

Tags: php, ajax

I'm not sure if I have done right when I use AJAX to send some info to a PHP-page with some code that connects to a database and stores a piece of text. A PHP-page that AJAX call, must that PHP-page be different compared to a common PHP-page? It's not working, I get a 404 Not Found message?

Here is the PHP-page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$replyArticleId = isset($_POST['replyArticleId']) ? $_POST['replyArticleId'] : '';
$replyText = isset($_POST['replyText']) ? $_POST['replyText'] : '';

$replySign = $_SESSION['accountId'];

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
$date = new DateTime();
$replyDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$tableUser = DB_PREFIX . WS_DB_USER;
$tablePost  = DB_PREFIX . WS_DB_POST;
$tableComment = DB_PREFIX . WS_DB_COMMENT;
$tableArticle = DB_PREFIX . WS_DB_ARTICLE;
$tableReply = DB_PREFIX . WS_DB_REPLY;

// Add new comment

$query1 = "INSERT INTO {$tableReply} (replyArticleId, replyText,replyUserId,        
replyDate) VALUES    ('{$replyArticleId}','{$replyText}','{$replySign}',  '{$replyDate}');";
$query2 = "UPDATE {$tableArticle} SET articleDateUpdated = NOW() WHERE articleId =     {$replyArticleId};";
$res = $mysqli->query($query1) or die($mysqli->error);
$res = $mysqli->query($query2) or die($mysqli->error);

$mysqli->close();
```

This is the AJAX code that I use to call and send some test content:

```
$.ajax({
url: "PAddReplyProcessAJAX.php?replyArticleId=1", 
type: "POST",
dataType: "text",
data: "replyText=" + "test"
}); 



?>
```

Comment: Check the url you are using.. try to access the same url in browser.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like JavaScript is not calling the PHP script where you think it is.

Open up the FireBug console (or Chrome developer tools) and see the exact URL that gets queried.

Try setting an absolute path for your script's URL to see if that helps. Depending on your URL structure, the relative paths may vary.

As side notes, your PHP script contains SQL injection vulnerabilities. Make sure you properly escape values or use bound parameters. You might not care about security in your application for whatever reason, but it will still crash whenever someone types in a bad character, like a single quote.

Comment: Interresting, "It looks like JavaScript is not calling the PHP script where you think it is." But could you explain how you mean in brief?

Comment: "Make sure you properly escape values or use bound parameters." How is that done?

Answer (score 1):

You supposed to use $_GET on this line (php page)

```
$replyArticleId = isset($_POST['replyArticleId']) ? $_POST['replyArticleId'] : '';

$replyArticleId = isset($_GET['replyArticleId']) ? $_GET['replyArticleId'] : '';
```

you're ajax type also should be 'GET'

if you want to pass a POST data you need to pass a valid variable data.

check on this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

you also have to make sure that the target file php is exists. Check the file name and file location.

Comment: I have tested GET before, but that didn't work! "if you want to pass a POST data you need to pass a valid variable data." ?? Is this not valid with POST. I want to use POST because the content comes from a form.

Comment: @3D-kreativ, If you want to passing form data then you need to serialized the form. You can use data : $('#formID').serialize(),

Answer (score 0):

Is that really the URL you want to use `PAddReplyProcessAJAX.php`?  Is it in the same directory as the page you're calling the ajax from?

Comment: This is all about your file names and website layout.  Is your web-server / file-system case sensitive, are you files in the right case, etc..?  Maybe update the question with real file and directory names and the two URLs (one for the page, one for the AJAX handler.)

Comment: I changed the file name to ajax_1.php , but still not working?